# Excel - For each Found Value Divide by Horizontal Ammount

Tags: database, excel, libreoffice, calc

Edit: Apparently asking for excel help invokes down votes? Please explain your reason for down-voting in comment. cause i cannot see a valid reason reading from the rules.

I find this hard to explain in words.
So i made an detailed image explaining what i am trying to achieve.
Should also be easier for the viewer.

[here is the image version (sorry dont have rights yet to embed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQVro.png)

Typed version:
I want to count for cells that `have a value` in vertically and cound those each as 15min. but i want to divide these 15min for each horizontal row of cells that `have a value` inside them.
The counting of cells i have already managed with =COUNTA its just that the recursive check part is what is confusing me.

I tried different methods like VLOOKUP and IF() but i could not get it to work correctly.

There is a the small mistake in the image.
it should not say 3:00:00 AM on the last row.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  I never adjusted for rounding
[image]